# How do I get a sharp display of icons generated by Image

Tags: python, image, icons, python-imaging-library, pyinstaller

I'm generating icons using Pillow Image. After that I generate an executable using pyinstaller. When I pin the executable to the taskbar the image looks unsharp.

[image]

```
def drawicon(text, imagesize, fontsize1, fontsize2, indent, iconfile):
    #build the icon
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (imagesize, imagesize), color='white')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("../fonts/calibri/CALIBRIB.ttf", fontsize1)
    draw.text((indent,0),'DEX',(255,0,0),font=font)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("../fonts/calibri/CALIBRIB.ttf", fontsize2)
    draw.text((indent,130),text,(0,0,0),font=font)
    img.save(iconfile, 'ICO', sizes = [(16, 16), (24, 24), (32, 32), (48, 48), (64, 64), (128, 128), (256, 256)])
```

What am I doing wrong?